# Injecting service beans doesnt work for Wicket pages mounted by AnnotatedMountScanner?

Tags: spring-boot, wicket

I have a simple Wicket 7.4.0 project when Wicket is configured inside of SpringBoot. I have @Service spring beans that want to inject into Wicket pages. Now when Wicket page is mounted by mountPage(..) command @Inject annotation works fine for wicket page. But @Inject doesnt work for wicket pages mounted by AnnotatedMountScanner() . Any idea whats wrong here? See my code snippet below.

```
@Override
  public void init() {
    super.init();

    getComponentInstantiationListeners().add(
        new SpringComponentInjector(this, applicationContext));

    new AnnotatedMountScanner().scanPackage("com").mount(this);
    mountPage("/x", PageAbout.class);

    getMarkupSettings().setDefaultMarkupEncoding("utf-8");

  }
```

**EDIT #1 - Full traceback I'm getting**

```
Unexpected RuntimeException

Last cause: Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: com.dubture.TestService.
WicketMessage: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.dubture.PageAbout(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' and argument ''. An exception has been thrown during construction!

Stacktrace

Root cause:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Concrete bean could not be received from the application context for class: com.dubture.TestService.
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.lookupSpringBean(SpringBeanLocator.java:275)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.SpringBeanLocator.locateProxyTarget(SpringBeanLocator.java:198)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.getFieldValue(AnnotProxyFieldValueFactory.java:150)
     at org.apache.wicket.injection.Injector.inject(Injector.java:111)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.inject(SpringComponentInjector.java:124)
     at org.apache.wicket.spring.injection.annot.SpringComponentInjector.onInstantiation(SpringComponentInjector.java:130)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:38)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection$1.notify(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:34)
     at org.apache.wicket.util.listener.ListenerCollection.notify(ListenerCollection.java:80)
     at org.apache.wicket.application.ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.onInstantiation(ComponentInstantiationListenerCollection.java:33)
     at org.apache.wicket.Component.<init>(Component.java:687)
     at org.apache.wicket.MarkupContainer.<init>(MarkupContainer.java:180)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:170)
     at org.apache.wicket.Page.<init>(Page.java:159)
     at org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage.<init>(WebPage.java:105)
     at com.dubture.PageAbout.<init>(PageAbout.java:33)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:171)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:76)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:102)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:271)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:329)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:203)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:284)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
     at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
     at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
     at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
     at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
     at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:784)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
     at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:802)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1410)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
     at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Complete stack:

org.apache.wicket.WicketRuntimeException: Can't instantiate page using constructor 'public com.dubture.PageAbout(org.apache.wicket.request.mapper.parameter.PageParameters)' and argument ''. An exception has been thrown during construction!
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:194)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:76)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:102)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:271)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:329)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
     at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:171)
     at org.apache.wicket.session.DefaultPageFactory.newPage(DefaultPageFactory.java:76)
     at org.apache.wicket.DefaultMapperContext.newPageInstance(DefaultMapperContext.java:102)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.resolvePageInstance(PageProvider.java:271)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageProvider.getPageInstance(PageProvider.java:169)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.PageRenderer.getPage(PageRenderer.java:78)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.isPageStateless(WebPageRenderer.java:287)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.shouldRenderPageAndWriteResponse(WebPageRenderer.java:329)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.handler.render.WebPageRenderer.respond(WebPageRenderer.java:193)
     at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.RenderPageRequestHandler.respond(RenderPageRequestHandler.java:175)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:895)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:265)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:222)
     at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:293)
     at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:261)
```

Comment: I see no connection between these two features: AnnotatedMountScanner works during initialization of the application only, SpringComponentInjector works on each an every instantiated component - whether it is a page, a mounted page or anything else. A quickstart would help to identify the problem.

Comment: The exception says that there is no such Bean in the Spring context. AnnotatedMountScanner actually does exactly the same as #mountPage() does.

Comment: Hmm, I tried again new simple project and its the same. Page mounted by mount() works fine with spring  @Inject, but page mounted with AnnotatedMountScanner  cant find spring bean as in error message above.

Comment: Do you use Spring Boot Devtools? Then you must configure Spring Boot Devtools to reload the annotated moutn scanner jar. There also exists also an Wicket Spring Boot Starter project for auto configuration